# re-prompting moves in Python

Tags: python, python-3.3, prompt

Where can I add a while loop in this code to ask for another move. I really need help I can't figure it out. I want it to re-prompt the move so when the move is invalid it will ask for another move again. And if the move is valid it will ask for the NEXT move?

```
def valid1(pile1):
    move = False
    pile1 = 3
    if pile1 == 0:
        print 'please choose from pile 2 and 3:'
    elif pile1 == 3:

        move = int(input('please choose the amount you would like:'))
        if move > 0 and move <= 2:
            pile1 = pile1 - move
        else:
            print 'you have entered a invalid move'
        return pile1
    elif pile1 == 2:

        move = int(input('please choose the amount you would like:'))
        if move > 0 and move <= 2:
            pile1 = pile1 - move
        else:
            print 'you have entered a invalid move'
        return pile1
    elif pile1 == 1:

        move = int(input('please choose the amount'))
        if move > 0 and move <= 1:
            pile1 = pile1 - move
        else:
            print 'you have entered a invalid move'
        return pile1
    else:
        print pile2


print valid1(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finding it a bit hard to understand your code precisely, so I'm not sure which bit to loop around, but I think if you use the following general principle you'll fix this:

```
 looping = True
 while looping = True :
     move = int(input('please choose the amount you would like:'))
        if move > 0 and move <= 2:
            pile1 = pile1 - move
        else:
            print 'you have entered a invalid move'
        return pile1
```

In the code above, you'll keep looping and so the input prompt will keep being asked after you've entered a move. If you want to break out of the loop when a certain condition is met, then after you've coded the condition put looping = False. In python, the first letter of Boolean values must be capitalized. There are other ways to do this, such as with break statements etc, but this is the method I prefer to use. As I said, I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted looping around in the code, but if you enclose it all in a 'while' statement like above, it should be fixed. Hope this helps!